# How to remove an item from array if it's been clicked (and if it already has been previously added to an array)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, framerjs

How do you remove an item from array if it's been clicked (and if it already has been previously added to an array)?

I have a Framer X (React) prototype which pulls down football betting information down from an API, like so:

```
const API = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/i461t"

// [1]
export const data = Data({
    matches: [],
    chosenBets: [],
})

// [2]
const fetchData = async (endpoint, callback) => {
    const response = await fetch(endpoint)
    const json = await response.json()
    data.matches = json
}
```

Each match has odds associated with it: for the home and away team, as well as a draw:

[image]

When the user selects an odd, it becomes highlighted and is added to a `chosenBets` array:

```
export function PopulateMatches(): Override {
    return {
        matches: data.matches,
        onClick(obj, index) {
            data.chosenBets.splice(index, 1, obj)
            console.log(data.chosenBets, "data.chosenBets")
        },
    }
}
```

[image]

When I click the same odd again, it is deselected (the red background removed from the button but not the data object `chosenBets`)

[image]

How do I remove the item from the `chosenBets` data object?

Code can be viewed here: https://github.com/A7DC/FramerXTEST1

Edit: full code

```
import * as React from "react"
import { Data, Override, Stack, Frame } from "framer"
import { MatchCard } from "./canvas"

//// Pulling down mathches

const API = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/i461t"

// [1]
export const data = Data({
    matches: [],
    chosenBets: [],
})

// [2]
const fetchData = async (endpoint, callback) => {
    const response = await fetch(endpoint)
    const json = await response.json()
    data.matches = json
}

// App.tsx
export function PopulateMatches(): Override {
    return {
        matches: data.matches,
        onClick(obj, index) {
            data.chosenBets.splice(index, 1, obj)
            console.log(data.chosenBets, "data.chosenBets")
        },
    }
}

// [4]
fetchData(API, {})
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question. We shouldn't have to go sift through a  repo just to review your initial problem. Questions should be self contained and external links used only to support what actually exists in the question itself. See [mcve]. Your images are far less useful than the code that produces the ui

Comment: I have updated the post with the full code, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) can also be used to remove an element from an array.

```
data.chosenBets.splice(index, 1); // Deletes the element at specified index.
```

Also, adding to `chosenBets` array looks wrong. Second argument should be `0` when adding.

```
data.chosenBets.splice(index, 0, obj); // Adds the element at specified index.
```

Then `onClick()` function would look like

```
onClick(obj, index) {
  if (data.chosenBets[index]) {
    // Remove object.
    data.chosenBets.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    // Add object.
    data.chosenBets.splice(index, 0, obj); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly @Nikhil :) I have accepted your answer as correct