# How to correctly update state in array using react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58099213/how-to-remove-an-item-from-array-if-its-been-clicked-and-if-it-already-has-bee/58099892?noredirect=1#comment102592326_58099892), I was given an answer on how to update an array, which was achieved in the following way:

```
onClick(obj, index) {
  if (data.chosenBets[index]) {
    // Remove object.
    data.chosenBets.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    // Add object.
    data.chosenBets.splice(index, 0, obj); 
  }
}
```

This does not trigger a re-render in my UI. How do I update the array (in the same way as above) while triggering a re-render?

Answer (score 1):

Just mutating a state won't trigger re-render. You need to call `setState()` function:

```js
// class component
onClick = () => {
  // update state
  this.setState(newState);
}

// functional component
...
  const [ state, setState ] = useState();

  ...

  setState(newState);
```

Also, it's quite important to perform immutable state updates since React relies on refs usually (especially, when using `memo()` or `PureComponent`). So, it's better to create new instance of array with the same items.

```js
onClick(obj, index) {
  let newData;
  if (data.chosenBets[index]) {
    newData = data.slice();
    newData.chosenBets.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    newData = [ obj, ...data ]; 
  }

  setState(newData);
}
```

And you always can use some libraties for immutable update like [immer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer), [object-path-immutable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-path-immutable) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try avoiding impure functions when writing react codes. Here, splice is an impure method. I would recommend using the below code:

```
onClick(obj, index) {
  if (this.state.data.chosenBets[index]) {
    // Remove object.
    const data = {
        ...this.state.data,
        chosenBets: this.state.data.chosenBets.filter((cBet, i) => i !== index)
    };
    this.setState({ data });
  } else {
    // Add object.
    const data = {
        ...this.state.data,
        chosenBets: [ ...this.state.data.chosenBets, obj ]
    };
    this.setState({ data }); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have that array already saved in your state. Then you can do something like this:

```
onClick = (idx) => {
  let arr = [...this.state.arrayToModify];
  arr.splice(idx,1);
  this.setState({ arrayToModify: arr });
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to make a copy of the array:

```
let arr = appState.chosenBets
arr.splice(index, 1)
appState.chosenBets = arr
```

Rather than simply doing

```
data.chosenBets.splice(index, 1);
```